# Dynamic UI Templates React Wont Update

Tags: javascript, reactjs

For my application I'm creating I want to be able to load new UI templates inside my React application while it is already deployed. The render function I'm using in my component will be empty initially, but the content I put here will be loaded from somewhere else as a text file.

For example I have a file called App.jsx which is the content that should go inside my render function:

```
<div>
    <AppHeader
        modules={props.modules}
        pathname={props.location.pathname}
        containerState={props.containerState}
    />
    <div className="app-window">
        <div className="app-content">{props.children}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

At runtime I fetch this App.jsx file and transform it into javascript:

```
React.createElement(
    "div",
    null,
    React.createElement(AppHeader, {
        modules: props.modules,
        pathname: props.location.pathname,
        containerState: props.containerState
    }),
    React.createElement(
        "div",
        { className: "app-window" },
        React.createElement(
            "div",
            { className: "app-content" },
            props.children
        )
    )
);
```

After I do the transform I then apply the javascript to a new function so I can execute the code. Something like this:

```
view = new Function(...args, "return " + template)(...argVals),

render() {
    return view;
}
```

While this works initially, the real issue is that my component wont update it's view when passed new props. Any advice on how I could potentially do this, while allowing my component to update when new props change?

Comment: Where exactly do you define `view`?

Comment: @Timo view originally lived inside the state of the individual component. Though when that is the case, any prop change you have to rebuild view entirely.